# language parameter with here geocoding

Tags: here-api

i am using the here geocoding and map tiles services.

geocoding search for oran, algeria returns address information in arabic.  map tiles for oran, algeria show address information in french.  here.com map site for oran, algeria also shows address information in french.  i would prefer geocoding information in english.  when making my geocoding request i have added "&language=en".  information returned in arabic.  i have also tried a request but with "&language=fr".  information returned in arabic.  is it possible to have geocoding information returned in english?  and, out of curiosity, since here seems to have the information in french when generating its tiles, is it possible to have geocoding information returned in french?

i notice that for, eg, tokyo, japan, the information is returned in english (or a sort of trans-literated englsh), not japanese.  the same is true for, eg, moscow, russia.  map information is in english, not cyrillic characters.

the only rule or guidance that i have found in the here documentation regarding language parameters concerns using a language list (&languages= ...)

thanks for any help.
- george ott

Answer (score 4):

When geocoding an address, the `language` parameter will only alter the exonym for the city and country. Take for example the Grote Markt/Grand Place in the center of Brussels.

- If you search for [Grand Place](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=grand%20place%20Bruxelles&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7) - the address is in *French*
- If you search for [Grand Place](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=grand%20place%20Bruxelles&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7&language=en) with `language=en` - the address is in French, the city and country are in *English*
- If you search for [Grote Markt](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=grote%20markt%20Brussel&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7) - the address is in *Dutch*
- If you search for [Grote Markt](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=grote%20markt%20Brussel&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7&language=en) with `language=en` - the address is in *Dutch*, the city and country are in *English*

If you want to obtain the *Dutch* name for the *French* street, you will need to make two requests - firstly a **geocoding request** to find out the longitude/latitude and then a  **reverse-geocoding request** to find out the local name of a location in the language of your choice.

For example Rue Bouzerki Mohamed/ نهج بوزركي محمد, وهران, الجزائر  is a street in Oran:

- Geocode the *Arabic* text to a location like [this](https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=%D9%86%D9%87%D8%AC%20%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B1%D9%83%D9%8A%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF,%20%D9%88%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86,%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7)
- Reverse Geocode to get the *French* name like [this](https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=35.69005%2C-0.65639%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=7&language=fr&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

It appears that as a general rule, the primary language is returned by default (for Algeria this is *Arabic*), but in the cases where a separate script is used an alternative may be returned. For an [English](https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=35.69005%2C-0.65639%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=7&language=en&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) language request, the road names in Algeria are returned in *French* (i.e. the standard 26 letter Roman Alphabet) rather than Arabic script.

The **Map Tiler** can display bilingual maps as shown below:

[image]

`lg=FRE&lg2=DUT` Map of Brussels at [zoom 10](https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/10/524/343/256/png8?lg=FRE&lg2=DUT&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

However the roads are only displayed in the primary language

[image]

`lg=FRE&lg2=DUT` Map of Brussels at [zoom 17](https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/17/67120/43968/256/png8?lg=FRE&lg2=DUT&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

Presumably this is due to the optimization of the label placements.

For languages with different scripts, **both labels** are shown

[image]

`lg=ARA&lg2=FRE` Map of Oran at [zoom 11](https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/1020/806/256/png8?lg=ARA&lg2=FRE&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

This includes the roads displayed in the secondary language at high zoom

[image]

`lg=ARA&lg2=FRE` Map of Oran at [zoom 17](https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/17/65309/51610/256/png8?lg=ARA&lg2=FRE&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

The list of languages available to the `lg` and `lg2` parameters can be found in the [Map Tile API Reference](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/api-reference/base/resource-base-maptile.html). Examples of [monolingual](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#map-tile/map-tile-language) and [bilingual](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#map-tile/map-tile-multi-language) maps tile can be found in the API Explorer

The `lg` and `lg2` can also be passed to the [Maps API For JavaScript](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html) as shown:

```
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'base'
    }),
    bilingualMapLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'normal.day',
      256,
      'png8',
      {lg: 'ARA', lg2: 'FRE'}
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(bilingualMapLayer);
```

Where `map` is an instance of an `H.Map` and `platform` is the 
`H.service.Platform` stub.

Comment: i'm not seeing the "lg=FRE&lg2=DUT" parameters in the map tiles documentation.  there is a reference to optional parameters in the api reference; it says to see the api "definition", but i don't 
see that.  only user guide and api reference (and i don't see "lg=" in either place).
i can simply follow the example you give, but i would like to read the
documentation.  

for the user who only speaks english or who only recognizes roman characters,
providing geocoded locations and maps in a recognizable alphabet is important.  i would
like to be able to do that wherever possible.

Comment: `lg` and `lg2` are documented in the Map Tile [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/api-reference/base/resource-base-maptile.html) - links added.